# Gridview disappears on edit event

Tags: c#

I have Dropdown and gridview on page dropdown bind frpom DB record on page load event and gridview bind on SelectedIndexChanged
event of dropdown fetch record on the basis of dropdown selection. And this is working fine but when we enable edit record in gridview my grid disappears
and we again fire selectedindex chage event of dropdown it will show in edit mode same happen on each event like cancel..
I am not able to manage state of gridview. KIndly help to manage(I had also try to using hidden field but not able to resolve the problem.)

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!  - And add at least a few line breaks to your question so people have not such a hard time reading it!